# Different ways to verify the text is overlapped or not in GUI using protractor

Tags: html, angularjs, browser, protractor, responsive

I'm testing responsive web page using protractor with mobile resolution of **300*640**.I have observed that the icon and some of text is getting overlapped but unable to identify using protractor.

I have used `isDisplayed()` function and return of `isDisplayed()` is **true** in my code as below:

```
const get Element= element(by.id('iconId'));
  return getElement.element(by.className('product-png')).isDisplayed().then((isVisible) => {
    return isVisible;
});
```

NOTE:: I want to know how to test the overlapped text or icon in protractor for responsive web-page and what all the scenarios to test any web page on mobile and tablet.

Comment: isDisplayed returns true if the element is present in the viewport, isPresent returns true if the element is present in the DOM. There is no way to check if two elements are overlapping without checking their coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to compare screenshots. You have designs made for different sizes of screens and then take a screenshot at that browser size and compare it with your design. This can be done better with UI Testing tools like Applitools and Percy. Check out this blog for more info [Percy](https://blog.percy.io/visual-testing-for-angular-apps-with-protractor-eb7a959b9d54).

P.S.
Percy is paid but it is definitely a good tool to have for UI testing.

Other complicated way of doing it would be to get the UI coordinates of elements you want to check for overlap. The coordinates should be different. If the coordinates of the second element is anywhere in the range of the first element's start to end coordinate, then there is an overlap. But this method would be really cumbersome unless you write a helper function that plots the coordinates of 4 points of the elements and compares it with the 4 points of the other element.

You could alternately use [jqueryCollision](https://sourceforge.net/p/jquerycollision/wiki/Home/) for checking this. Look at the documentation.